# flutter_bloc - hook into onClose, onCreate lifecycle events for specific cubit

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I want to hook into the lifecycle events of my cubits.

I notice the blocObserver has `onClose` and `onCreate`, however that is for observing all cubit's lifecycle events. How do I hook into these events just for a specific cubit? For example the equivalent of overriding `onClose` inside a cubit.

My implementation of ChessMax's answer:

```
class VpCubit<T> extends Cubit<T> {
  VpCubit(T initial) : super(initial);

  void onClose() => print('');

  @override
  Future<void> close() async {
    if (onClose != null) {
      onClose();
    }

    return super.close();
  }
}

class LoggedOutNickNameCubit extends VpCubit<int> {
  LoggedOutNickNameCubit()
      : super(0);

  @override
  void onClose() {
    print('closing');
  }

  void onCreate() {
    print('creating');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to filter out events in the observing hook. Every event of BlocObserver has a reference to a cubit/bloc instance that sends the event. So you can compare it with the reference with your specific cubit/bloc instance. And if references are equal you can handle it somehow. Something like this:

```
  class MyObserver extends BlocObserver {

  final Cubit<Object> _cubit;

  MyObserver(this._cubit) : assert(_cubit != null);

  @override
  void onClose(Cubit cubit) {
    if (cubit == _cubit) {
      // do whatever you need
    }
    
    super.onClose(cubit);
  }
}
```

Another way is to create your own cubit/bloc subclass. Override the methods you want to listen to. And use your own BlocObserver like class to notify this specific cubit/bloc listeners. Something like this:

```
class MyObserver {
  final void Function() onClose;

  MyObserver(this.onClose);  
}

class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyEvent, MyState> {
  final MyObserver _observer;
  MyBloc(this._observer) : super(MyInitial());


  @override
  Future<void> close() async {
    if (_observer != null && _observer.onClose != null) {
      _observer.onClose();
    }
    
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

Also, I think, it's possible to write a generic cubit/bloc wrapper base class like above. And then use it as a base class for all your cubits/blocs classes instead.

Comment: Thanks! I will accept your answer. I just thought I would ask first if it is possible to add `onCreate` to your solution? I slightly simplified the design by not having the observer. I have posted my implementation in the bottom of my question and it works, but not for `onCreate`.  I also had to implement `void onClose() => print('');` in the parent class because when I instead put `void Function() onClose;`, it for some reason thought it was not an override and gave me a `cannot have method with the same name` error which seems weird.

Comment: Its a shame that it wont work for both Cubit and Bloc. Since `Bloc` extends `Cubit`, not `VpCubit`. I might have to do a `VpBloc` too. Unless I can somehow use the `on` keyword to extend `Cubit`, making `Bloc` extend that extension.

Comment: You can do it like that: `VpCubit(T initial) : super(initial) {onCreate();}`

Comment: >Unless I can somehow use the on keyword to extend<
I don't think it's possible in dart.